# How can I set default value to an attribut in the parent constructor?

Tags: c#, oop, constructor

I have two constructor :

```
public abstract class A
{
    public A(int a,int b = 0 ) {}
} 

public class B : A
{
    public B(int a , int b):base(a,b) {} // I would like to didn't call again the attribute b 
       // because it's set to 0 in the parent class 
      //   public B(int a):base(a) {} 
}
```

Maybe my question was ridiculous but I'm searching for a trick to avoid the repeat of calling an attribute with default set to 0 in the parent class, In fact, I have many child classes

Is it possible to do that?

**Update :**

This is an instance of B created in MainWindow :

```
B b1 = new B(1); // a = 1 and b = 0 by default 
B b2 = new B(2,1) // I would like to update the value b and set it to 1 for in the second instance created , In this case I got an error 
// B does not contains a constructor that takes 2 arguments ...
```

Comment: And what's wrong with `public B(int a) : base(a) { }`?

Comment: The problem is that when I call class B , for example , I need to set some instances value's b to 1 , I will update my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this would be to overload the constructor in `B`:

```
public class B : A
{
    public B(int a) : base(a) { }
    public B(int a, int b) : base(a, b) { }
}
```